# !Unknownsymbol! when writing java class for sonarqube

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

Hi StackOverflow community,

I am new to writing custom rules for java in SonarQube.

I am writing a custom rule to detect certain interfaces being in used via maven. However, during testing, "!unknownSymbol!" came out instead of the Interface classes being implemented by the test case.

In my test case, I have written a class which implements 2 interfaces: -
- java.util.List
- org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator

The test can detect both interfaces, but when I convert it into a symbolTree then use the method fullyQualifiedName(), it returns "!unknownSymbol!". However, when I am doing a simple toString() it returns the interface name.

I would like to know how to correctly convert it into a symbolTree object and get the correct interface without encountering "!unknownSymbol!"

Thank you very much.

The code:

```
package org.sonar.samples.java.checks;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import org.sonar.check.Priority;
import org.sonar.check.Rule;
import org.sonar.plugins.java.api.IssuableSubscriptionVisitor;
import org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.ClassTree;
import org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.ListTree;
import org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.Tree;
import org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.TypeTree;

import java.util.List;

@Rule(
        key = "AvoidInterfaceClass",
        name = "No Interfaces",
        description = "Not allowed to implement any interface(s)",
        priority = Priority.MAJOR
)

    public class AvoidSuperInterfacesRule extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor {

    public static final List<String> SUPER_INTERFACE_AVOID = ImmutableList.of("org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator","java.util.List");

    @Override
    public List<Tree.Kind> nodesToVisit() {
        return ImmutableList.of(Tree.Kind.CLASS);
    }

    public void visitNode(Tree tree){

        //System.out.println("Here");

        ClassTree treeClass = (ClassTree) tree;

        if (treeClass.superInterfaces().isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        ListTree<TypeTree> superInterfaceNames = treeClass.superInterfaces();

        System.out.println(superInterfaceNames.size()); //Number of interfaces
        System.out.println();

        for (TypeTree t:superInterfaceNames){

            String name = t.symbolType().fullyQualifiedName();

            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(t.toString());

            System.out.println();

            if (SUPER_INTERFACE_AVOID.contains(name)){
                reportIssue(t, "This interface is not allowed to be implemented.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The output:

```
09:18:36.332 [main] INFO org.sonar.squidbridge.ProgressReport - 1 source files to be analyzed
09:18:36.439 [main] DEBUG org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - ----- Classpath analyzed by Squid:
09:18:36.439 [main] DEBUG org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - C:\Users\attanyg1\Desktop\Sonarqube\java-custom-rules\target\test-jars\commons-collections4-4.0.jar
09:18:36.439 [main] DEBUG org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - C:\Users\attanyg1\Desktop\Sonarqube\java-custom-rules\target\test-jars\javaee-api-6.0.jar
09:18:36.439 [main] DEBUG org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - C:\Users\attanyg1\Desktop\Sonarqube\java-custom-rules\target\test-jars\spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
09:18:36.440 [main] DEBUG org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - C:\Users\attanyg1\Desktop\Sonarqube\java-custom-rules\target\test-jars\spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
09:18:36.440 [main] DEBUG org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - C:\Users\attanyg1\Desktop\Sonarqube\java-custom-rules\target\test-jars\spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar
09:18:36.440 [main] DEBUG org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - C:\Users\attanyg1\Desktop\Sonarqube\java-custom-rules\target\test-classes
09:18:36.440 [main] DEBUG org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - -----

2 -> Number of Interfaces

!unknownSymbol! -> symbolType.getFullyQualifiedName()
BundleActivator -> toString()

!unknownSymbol! -> symbolType.getFullyQualifiedName()
List            -> toString()

09:18:36.798 [Report about progress of Java AST analyzer] INFO org.sonar.squidbridge.ProgressReport - 1/1 source files have been analyzed
```

Comment: Can you share the code with the problem and the exact error message? Especially if the message points out the exact location of the problem. When you do, please do copy-paste text as much as possible, instead of screenshots

Comment: I have inserted the code together with the error messages. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in test environment, after some debugging found that org.sonar.java.checks.verifier.internal.InternalCheckVerifier has classpath field, which was set by default to FilesUtils.getClassPath("../java-checks-test-sources/target/test-jars"), also it has org.sonar.java.checks.verifier.internal.InternalCheckVerifier#withClassPath method, tried to set the classpath with this method and this helped me:

```
CheckVerifier.newVerifier()
            .withClassPath(FilesUtils.getClassPath("target/test-jars"))
            .onFile("src/test/files/AvoidLiteralsInSqlCriteriaRuleVictim.java")
            .withCheck(new AvoidLiteralsInSqlCriteriaRule())
            .verifyIssues();
```

Also you should configure copying of this jars to the target folder in maven-dependency-plugin, e.g.:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                <version>8.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-jars</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```